# Forward from Spring Boot to a specific Angular component

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, spring-boot

In my web app the Angular UI is served as static resource from a Spring Boot application (by copying the built Angular app into the */resources/static* folder of the Spring Boot app).

All of my Spring endpoints are prefixed with `/api`.

The relevant routes from the Angular app:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
```

This works fine, when i start the Spring Boot app and navigate to `http://localhost:8080` in the browser, then the login page of the Angular app is shown.

The problematic part:

Navigating directly to the login or registration pages by pasting `http://localhost:8080/login` or `http://localhost:8080/registration` into the browser and hitting enter won't work, because the request will hit the Spring Boot app and since it has no matching mapping, it will return 404.

The first thing i did was obviously to search for a solution on Stackoverflow and most answers suggested to forward the requests to the root with a matching mapping, so i've added the following `Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping({"/login", "/registration"})
    public String forward() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

This solves the 404 errors.

The problem is even if i navigate directly to `http://localhost:8080/registration`, i got forwarded to the login page and the `LoginComponent` is shown.

What i would like to achieve is when i navigate to `http://localhost:8080/registration` in the browser, then indeed go to the registration page and show the `RegistrationComponent` of the Angular app.

Is this even possible? If so, i'd really appreaciate any advice on how to achieve it.

Comment: The behavior you're observing is caused by code that you're not showing us. Everything looks right in what you posted.

Comment: @JBNizet Unfortunately i don't know what part of the code could be relevant regarding this problem. If you could point me in the right direction i would happily add the missing part. I just didn't want to flood the question with irrelevant code.

Comment: Look for any piece of code in your frontend using navigate or navigateByUrl, and which would navigate to the login page.

Comment: @JBNizet I've found the problem (see my answer below), thank you very much.

Comment: @justanoob Thanks for your question and answer. I t seemed awkward first, then I realised what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out i'm just stupid, thanks to [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407) for his comment.

The posted code in the question is correct, but i've added the following snippet recently to my `AppComponent` in the Angular app (and kinda forgot about it):

```
this.authService.currentAuth
  .subscribe(auth => {
    if (!auth) { // navigate to login if the user is not authenticated
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  });
```

Which is just plain wrong and this is what was causing the problem.